# ctx.drawImage doesn't draw while given correct img

Tags: javascript

I have an file input and iI want to draw the selected filein a canvas.

Calling a function that draws the img works.

```
fileselect.addEventListener("change", () => {
if(fileselect.files[0].type === "image/png" || fileselect.files[0].type === "image/jpg"){
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileselect.files[0])
    console.log(reader)
}
});

reader.onload = () => {
img.src = reader.result
console.log(img)
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
```

btw. the console.log returns a correct base 64 string

Comment: First parameter of drawImage expects a DOM img element (and some other things) but not a string. [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

Comment: the img var is an element